# Microsoft visual studio "setup blocked"

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When I try to install Microsoft visual studio 2015 it gives the error "Setup Blocked". telling me:"The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again."
after doing so it still doesn't work...
I'm on Windows 10 Build 10130
this is the last bit of the log file:

```
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:06]i101: Detected package: VSSetupUtility_Complete_vs_community, state: Absent, cached: None
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:06]i000: MUX:  Setup update feature is enabled. Evaluating conditions to determine whether to run setup update.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:06]i000: MUX:  Checking http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=500683 for update.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: Could not download update data.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]e000: MUX:  WARNING: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res, String arg)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
       at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
       at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.DownloadManager.DownloadXml(String url, Int32& returnCode)
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i000: MUX:  Failed to download the update xml file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=500683 Setup will not be updated.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (WindowsBuildNumber < 9600)' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 0' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '(NOT IsLanguagePack) AND ( CurrentOperation = "Install" ) AND ( FLP_Version > v14.0.22823 )' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to true.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition 'NOT (IEsvcVersionExists) OR (IEsvcVersion < v10.0)' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '(VersionNT < v6.2) AND ((NetworkAvailable = 0) OR (DisableRootAutoUpdate = 1)) AND NOT ((MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011AuthRootExists) AND (MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010AuthRootExists))' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '( CurrentOperation = "Install" AND EnterpriseExists )' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '( CurrentOperation = "Install" AND UltimateExists )' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '( CurrentOperation = "Install" AND NOT EnterpriseExists AND ProfessionalExists)' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (KB2919355_amd64_CurrentState <> 112 AND KB2919355_x86_CurrentState <> 112)' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.22816)' evaluates to false.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: SystemRebootPendingBlock : The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
    [0A60:139C][2015-07-10T18:48:07]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:08]i000: MUX:  View loaded
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:08]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: SystemRebootPendingBlock : The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:08]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
    [0A60:1530][2015-07-10T18:48:08]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

and [this](http://pastebin.com/BdzExZCG) is [the full log](http://pastebin.com/BdzExZCG)

Answer (score 35):

It seems that from Windows 8 onward shutting down doesn't actually turns the computer off, but rather hibernates it. That causes system files which the installer needed to operate on to continue being used.

You can turn hibernation off by running the following command as an administrator:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

After running it, restart the computer and the setup should work. You can turn it on again by using

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```

Comment: Good answer it worked ! but when I tried to run the second command to hibernate on, I get the error : An unexpected error (0x65b) has occurred:  Function failed during execution. By any chance did you get that error and do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: @omachu23 Did you run it as admin?

Comment: @gabrieljcs That was the problem. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 choices:

- Restart PC (not shutdown!)

OR

- If you dont want to restart pc, just use [**ignore-restart.bat**](https://puvox.software/blog/visual-studio-needs-to-be-restarted/) script before installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to Control panel; power options; Choose what the power buttons do; Change settings that are currently unavailable; then uncheck the 'Turn on fast startup(recommended)' check box, save the changes then shut down.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to bypass the same error on Windows 7 x64 by:

- emptying Windows Temp folder (usually `C:\Windows\Temp`), but keeping all files in use
- performing a restart

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue but my problem was something completely different.

The issue was that I was trying to install:

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (x86 and x64) - Web Installer (Multiple Languages)

Not:

Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 1 (x86 and x64) - Web Installer (English)

The error message is not helpful, but in my case it meant that i didnt have 2015 installed, so the update 1 couldn't be applied.

msdn forum post here for more info:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c531ef3-6c95-4dc9-a9a3-d23cc95b09c3/vs2015-update-1-setup-blocked-update-1-does-not-apply-or-is-blocked-by-another-condition-on-your?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0):

Just go to command prompt and run the below:
SHUTDOWN /r /f /t 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because an instance of previous installation required a reboot and the reboot required is still in the registry. Although with reboot the "reboot required" key should have been deleted from the registry, but it is still existing in registry.

The solution is to manually delete the "reboot required" key and then try to setup/uninstall the visual studio.

The key is located in -
"**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{9600393b-6ede-469b-a522-689fce1461d1}.RebootRequired**"

Locate the key and delete it. Then try to install/uninstall/repair the visual studio.