# Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 4 Setup Blocked, computer needs to restart

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm attempting to install Visual Studio Community 2015, but it is consistently giving me this error:

[image]

I've restarted multiple times with no luck. Log is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8lsnoexyj9oh7y/vslog.log?dl=0

Nobody else seems to have my problem, except on Windows 8 and above, when the OS goes into hibernation rather than shutting down. Running Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has to do with the power settings on windows from 8.1 onwards. Power off actually puts the computer on hibernate mode. I had this same issue with VS community update 1. I fixed the issue with the following steps:

1. run cmd as administrator
2. enter `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`
3. restart computer (it may freeze on "getting windows ready" screen, just hold power button down and turn your computer back afterwards)
4. `powercfg.exe /hibernate on` (Run cmd as administrator again to turn the hibernate setting back on)
5. reinstall visual studio community 2015

This is a solution I came up with while trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked)

Alternatively, you can turn off "fast startup" in the windows power settings.

1. In windows 10: Open "Power and sleep settings"
2. Click "Additional Power settings"
3. Click "Choose what the power buttons do"
4. Click "change settings that are currently unavailable"
5. Under "shutdown settings", untick the box that says "Turn on fast startup"

Answer (score 0):

I know that situation. Simple restart wont help.  You should do real "Restart" from start, or if you don want to restart, use [`fix-for-restart-needed.bat`](https://www.protectpages.com/blog/visual-studio-needs-to-be-restarted/) script.