# VS 2015 Community Installation - Newer Windows Version required

Tags: windows, installation, visual-studio-2015, version

I've been trying to install VS 2015 Community on my main computer. It is running under Windows 10 which I upgraded to a few months ago from Windows 7 Home Premium. Now I also have VS 2012 Express installed if that is a neccessary information.

However everytime I try run the vscommunity.exe to install VS 2015 I get this error message:
[image: Error]

Translated this basically means:

> This program requires a newer version of Windows

Sorry I can only get this message in German.

Comment: I had no problem doing exactly the same thing, other than my Windows version is English.  Perhaps there is some bug with VS2015 recognizing the German localized version.

Comment: Hmn. The funny thing is it installed correctly on my laptop where I had VS 2013 installed and Win 8.1 as OS. It kinda seems like it thinks I'm still using Win7 because I read some peoples posts about having trouble installing it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellu again.

I found a solution to the problem. So first I could've tried starting it as administrator ^^. This brought up the vs installation window.

When the installation came up it showed me the error "Setup Blocked" and told me to restart the computer. Obviously I have done this before so this couldn't be the solution. Thanks through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked) I found out that I needed to turn off hibernation and then restart the computer to fix it.

To turn off hibernation just open the command line and type:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

And to turn it back on again:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```

After restarting the installation worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off hibernation also worked for me

Cmd: powercfg.exe /hibernate off

Complete the installation and then to turn it back on again:

Cmd: powercfg.exe /hibernate on