# Visual studio 2013 community setup blocked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, installation

So I'm starting to practice with Unreal engine but I have to install Visual studio community 2013 but I get this setup blocked notification and It says that I have to restart PC I've looked up about this problem and it's all about actually rebooting Pc and what not but it still doesn't seem to fix the problem
http://pastebin.com/psJ1XVdF Thats the full log

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked

Comment: I've tried that, still doesn't work