# Not able to uninstall Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I try to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 ( because i already have 2013 and 2017 version). When  i try the process : **Control Panel** => **Programs and Features** => **Change** (choosing the product) , it always says:

> You need to restart your computer in order to proceed

I've done that many times. Also looking at the log file i can see that information

> Stop Block: SystemRebootPendingBlock

I've also tried the suggestion to turn the hibernation off explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked)

NB: I have some pending update in my machine when i restart, some fail, don't know why. I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: *"I have some pending update in my machine when i restart, some fail, don't know why."* That's what you need to figure out. What are they, and why are they failing?

Comment: They are specific to Office 2013, SQl server 2014 and one for windows defender